# Why is this rule not consuming the first character [Prolog CFG]?

Tags: parsing, prolog, grammar, swi-prolog

I am trying to write a rule for wrapping elements but when entering the recursive rule, the first element is still being included, maybe I am not understanding correctly the syntax but the comma shouldn't go to the next element?

```
% [First] should be consumed (note: charcode 194 is for the backtick character)
backticks(L) --> [First], {char_code(First,194), writeln(["first was backtick",First])}, nobackticks(L), {writeln(["identifier",L])}.
nobackticks([]) --> [Last], {char_code(Last,194),writeln(["last is backtick",Last])}.
nobackticks([X|Xs]) --> [X], nobackticks(Xs), {writeln(["checking backticks",X,Xs])}.
%run recursively until it finds the last backtick
```

Test

```
:- string_chars("´backticks´",Text), phrase(backticks(X),Text,[]), writeln(X).
```

Output:

```
[first was backtick,´]
[last is backtick,´]
[checking backticks,s,[]]
[checking backticks,k,[s]]
[checking backticks,c,[k,s]]
[checking backticks,i,[c,k,s]]
[checking backticks,t,[i,c,k,s]]
[checking backticks,k,[t,i,c,k,s]]
[checking backticks,c,[k,t,i,c,k,s]]
[checking backticks,a,[c,k,t,i,c,k,s]]
[checking backticks,b,[a,c,k,t,i,c,k,s]]
[checking backticks,´,[b,a,c,k,t,i,c,k,s]]
[identifier,[´,b,a,c,k,t,i,c,k,s]]
```

Expected output:

```
[identifier,[b,a,c,k,t,i,c,k,s]]
```

Finally the rule is not successful

Answer (score -1):

If you run `?- char_code(´,C).` you get `C=180` (at least in SWISH). So you need to change `194` to `180` in your code and you will get the desired output:

```
[first was backtick, ´]
[last is backtick, ´]
[checking backticks, s, []]
[checking backticks, k, [s]]
[checking backticks, c, [k, s]]
[checking backticks, i, [c, k, s]]
[checking backticks, t, [i, c, k, s]]
[checking backticks, k, [t, i, c, k, s]]
[checking backticks, c, [k, t, i, c, k, s]]
[checking backticks, a, [c, k, t, i, c, k, s]]
[checking backticks, b, [a, c, k, t, i, c, k, s]]
[identifier, [b, a, c, k, t, i, c, k, s]]
[b, a, c, k, t, i, c, k, s]
true
false
```

Comment: Thanks but that is not working for me, though I have found that a backtick counts as two consecutive characters 194 and 180 so I have changed my code